# JQuery colorbox strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

I have a strange problem. I work actually on the plugin jquery.colorbox.js.The purpose of my program is to display a simple html page with a link to a colorbox displaying an image. The problem comes from the linkage with the css file. If I put the URL href="colorbox.css" it works perfectly but with this one href="css/colorbox.css" the animation seems to be good but there is no background and the colorbox is just a white square with the image correctly displayed in its center. But all the cool effects are absent.
I have 3 folders into my main project folder plus the index.html and a copy of the file colorbox.css:

Folder images : palmiers.jpg
Folder css    : colorbox.css
Folder js     : jquery.min.js jquery.colorbox-min.js

File : colorbox.css
File : index.html

Here is the content of the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>ColorBox Examples</title>
        <style>
            body
            {
                background-color:#666;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css"/>
        <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#image").colorbox({width:'500', height:'500'});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a id="image" href="images/palmiers.jpg">link to the lightBox</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So If I change this line of code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css"/>
```

By :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="colorbox.css"/>
```

The colorbox is displayed is correctly. But I want to have all my css files into the css folder. Why when I change the linkage I have two different behaviour? The two colorbox.css files are exactly the sames.

Does anyone can help me? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Using the `css/colorbox.css` in your code, open up Index.html in Google Chrome, right-click, view source, in your `head` tag `css/colorbox.css` should be a link. Click the link. What happens? Do you see a styles? Post the URL here

Comment: The style section is : inline element {}. It's empty but html source code is the same that mine.

Comment: Sorry the prevent answer is wrong. I clicked on the 'css/colorbox.css' link and it allows access to the whole content of the file colorbox.css. But it's a huge content. I can't post it here in its entirety. So the linkage seems to be correct. That's why I'm going to be crazy.

Comment: Please post the URL you see in your browser after clicking on `css/colorbox.css`

Comment: I recommend to use Chrome and hit F12 Key and view Console for any GET errors. It will say what it could **not get** by listing path/file that was expected. And to be sure, both **colorbox.css** file names should be the same filesize in bytes... right?

Comment: The self closing tag for the link needs to have 1 blank space before the forward slash. Example: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="colorbox.css" />`

Comment: Yes but if I can access to the whole content of the 'colorbox.css' file clicking on the URL on the console, it means it shoudn't have any errors right?

Comment: I did what you said. Effectively, I have some GET errors : overlay.png border.png and controls.png have failed -> 404 Not found. The inititor is the script file jquery.min.js. This the first time I use this tool. Can you explain me why these files loading have failed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding base tag inside you head tag with your project url, like:

```
<head>
<base href="http://your_site_url" />
```

Not sure but this might help

Comment: Hello. I'm in localhost so my URL starts by "file:///C:...". I put it into my head section and it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @user1450730: I would recommend avoiding this approach simply because of the need to remember to change it... which you wont remember to do all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this question is really related to any of your tags, this is more a simple reference issue.

You can specify an 'absolute' path by prefix your path with a `/` character, providing your 'css' folder is a root directory folder then this should work...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/colorbox.css"/>
```

without the `/` prefix you are essentially declaring a 'relative' path which mean the full path will start within the current directory (i.e. wherever the current file is)

Comment: Hello. I already tried this solution but the result is worse: there is an animation followed by the display of the image but now there is no white square. Only the image are on the screen.

Comment: @user1450730: then I suspect your folder structure may be wrong, are you sure you are not using any other folders which might affect this? Can you access this URL? : `localhost/css/colorbox.css`

Comment: Absolutly sure : In my main folder I have my index.html plus the others three folders containing the css, js and jpeg files. It's just when I put the href="colorbox.js" URL that it works. It's crazy! The "localhost/css/colorbox.css" URL doesn't works. On CakePHP framework it's the same problem.

Comment: How are you hosting the site? Visual Studio development server? I have just tried the equivalent on one of my css files and it works fine... also, do you have any virtual directory settings?

Comment: No it's just a test program in localhost. I edited it with Notepad++. And I tried first with the framework CakePHP edited with eclipse and it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: I see, then this may be a settings in your hosting environment that prevents the use of absolute paths, are you using IIS to host or does Eclipse have something built in? (I have not used eclipse for web work before) ...actually forget the IIS (pretty sure if you are using PHP it wont be possible in IIS)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the result of the plugin not finding it's own image assets (not your image).

ColorBox's own CSS file refers to the image assets it uses.  It makes an assumption about where those assets will be stored.  To use any arbitrary location, you'll need to edit ColorBox's own CSS file to use that location.